# Transparent white button looks bad in Android Material Design

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, google-maps-android-api-2, transparency

Consider these 2 screenshots. I defined the elements on the left, top, and bottom-right:

[image]
[image]

The left/top screenshot has all my elements using a solid white (`#FFFFFF`) while the bottom/right one adds a bit of transparency (`#D0FFFFFF`). **My issue is that my elements look hideous with transparency. For example the FAB (bottom-right) contains a smaller opaque circle for no reason.**

All my elements have elevation 6 (as that is the FAB default elevation). Anything greater-than elevation 2 has this issue clearly visible, and anything below 2 does not cast enough shadow for me to look acceptable.

**The Maps-defined element (top-right) seems completely unaffected by this however!** What is it doing differently? It's clearly using transparency like me and also casting a shadow corresponding to elevation 2 or more.

Code used is basically this:

```
fab = FloatingActionButton(this.context!!)
fab.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#d0ffffff"))
fab.compatElevation = 6F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example the FAB (bottom-right) contains a smaller opaque circle
> for **no reason**.

later on... `fab.compatElevation = 6F`

The circle you are seeing it's FAB's shadow, which is generated by the elevation.
If you want to remove the shadow but keep the elevation, do:

```
fab.outlineProvider = null
```

If you want to keep both elevation and shadow, you have to make a custom outlineProvider (probably a banana shaped one).

Comment: Ah, I had a hunch it was the FAB's shadow on the ground/map! I do want the black shadow around the object though (isn't this the reason why you would use an elevation?), so sadly `fab.outlineProvider = null` does not make me happy. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to make a custom outline, you can make the shadow yourself with multiple layers of shades of grey as GradientDrawable and add it as the background of FAB. I don't think there's any out-of-the-box solution to your issue.